# Is there any operator in typescript or javascript that ignores keys from result array that are not present in the class?

Tags: angular, typescript, postgresql, supabase

I am receiving an array from database which will have a lot of keys. But instead of assigning all the keys, I have already defined the class and just want to bind only the keys that are in the class and ignore others.

For example,

`[{cpuSpeed: null, cpuName: null, caseName: 'ABC', caseColor: 'Black'}]`

In this array I just want to bind `Case` related properties to `Case[]` and ignore `CPU` properties. Is there anything available so that there is a strict binding?
I have tried type assertion `as` syntax

I am using Angular and Supabase (Postgressql)

For clarification this is my function:

```
const case = await this.supabaseService.supabase
    .rpc('selectAllDBFunction', {
      "param": 'case'
    })
    .returns<Case[]>()
    let lstcase = case.data
```

the `selectAllDBFunction` returns the an array like above with all the keys, I just want to bind only `Case` related keys to `const case`

This is the case class:

```
Export class Case{
  caseName: string;
  caseColor: string;
}
```

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when others copy and paste it into their own IDEs.

Comment: "*I have already defined the class*" - please show us that definition. You probably will have to do `data.map(obj => new Case(obj.casename, obj.caseColor))` or something similar

Comment: Does your `class Case` not have a constructor or any methods? Doesn't look like it would compile like that.

Comment: I have added the class. If map is the only solution then I might have to rewrite the backend query because there can be >2000 records.

Comment: No it doesnt have constructor, it compiles and works fine but when I console log the array after it assigned, it have all the unwanted keys that are not related to class Case

Comment: Weird, [when I try this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GF3AN4BQciuAcigLbABccaMUAlgHYDmA3ESWsFhEtFr0mbTgF8gA) I get an error "*Property has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.*" You probably should use an `interface` declaration instead.

Comment: My tsconfig is probably different. I will try adding constructor to see if it solve the issue.